# Javascript mathematics

Tags: javascript, math, charts

Hey I have an equation that I need to figure out it is chart based math where you have two points on the chart and need to get the rest of the values:

I am building a javascript page that takes the takes the two points on a chart but needs to spit out any position on the chart.

It is for extrapolating the sight settings on an archery site based on knowing two distances and sight settings:

Max Setting on sight: Var = 120;

```
Distances
18M
20M
25M
30M
35M
40M
45M
50M
55M
60M
70M
90M
```

The user would provide the following via form elements.

Shortest recorded sight setting Yardage and Site setting position E.G. 45M = 50
Longest recorded sight setting Yardage and Site setting position E.G. 70M = 105

Max Setting on site = 120

Distance they would like to get an estimation for (same list as above)

What the equation would do is guess the site setting for the yardage selected as long as they have entered the two previous settings.

For some reason I am lost trying to figure out the math for this.

Comment: Sounds like linear interpolation. Are you trying to fit a line to the two points, and then find the corresponding Y value for a 3rd point given it's X?

Comment: Exactly what I am trying to accomplish!

Comment: Are you talking about a _straight_ line? (I don't know much about archery, but don't you have to allow for arrows following a curved path?)

Comment: Not really it is a best guess calculator that will give you a starting point for your sight slider. So a straight line will work. Basically I shoot at 20M and 70M mostly during practice.(as do many of the archers) I have sight settings for those distances. What I am trying to write is a quick tool to give me a starting point for any other yardage. I want to make it for other archers so they might have different distances recorded but for the math of course we will need a MIN of two settings and distances entered as well as the target distance they are trying to get the setting for.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, really cool question!

I generally rely on Kentucky windage, but this seems to be a much more precise approach!

I have a solution, I didnt bother creating the form inputs but rather just created some static inputs.

```
var max = {"distance" : 70,"sight" : 105};
var min = {"distance" : 45,"sight" : 50};
var calculateSightSetting = function(dist,min,max){
  var distRange,distFactor,sightRange,returnDistance;
  if (dist < min.distance){
      throw "Distance provided must be at least " + min.distance + " M Long";
  }else{
      distRange = max.distance - min.distance;
      distFactor = ((dist-min.distance)/distRange);
      sightRange = max.sight-min.sight;
      returnDistance = min.sight + (sightRange * distFactor);
  }
  return returnDistance;
}                  
console.log(calculateSightSetting(60,min,max));
```

I have also created a JSFiddle so you can run it and see if it performs as expected.

http://jsfiddle.net/marteljn/rtYRZ/4/

Comment: Thanks for the work on this it looks promising. I have worked out something that seems to work well using Linear Interpolation.

Comment: It looks like we are doing the exact same thing.  The values on your solution are identical to mine.

Comment: Funny how there are so many ways to do the same thing. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input everyone,

I think I have gotten it figured out you can check out the solution at

http://matthewchitty.com/archery

(note it is javascript so you can view the source and check out the code.)

Ended up being pretty simple one I figured out the interpolation.